# How to implement the d3.time.scale linear time scale in Rickshaw?

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

I developed a small D3 example for an application I'm prototyping and in it the x-axis is defined on a time scale. I'm looking for compatible functionality in Rickshaw for time-series graphing, but I can't find a compatible way of putting a time scale on the x-axis in Rickshaw.

Supposedly you can call D3, but I'm not sure how that would be accomplished with the given Rickshaw implementation.

All help appreciated.

Thanks.

Les

Comment: Not sure what you mean. [Here](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/scaled.html) is an example with a time scale and axis -- what do you want to do differently?

Comment: That may be what I'm looking for. I was assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that Rickshaw wrapped D3 in a friendlier manner but still called D3 under the covers. Clearly in the RickShaw.Graph.Axis.Time.js file there is no reference to D3. Also adding to the confusion was the example in the package in the milliseconds.html file that uses a time fixture passed into Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time. Why does the example you referenced not use a time fixture?

Comment: I don't really know Rickshaw, so I can't answer that question.